# Create a responsive dashboard - Angular

Tags: angular, mat-card

I am trying to create a dashboardw the below layout:
[image]

I am using mat-card and have done the following:

```
<mat-card class="outer-card fadeInDown" style="max-width:50%;">
.
.
.
.
.
</mat-card>



<mat-card class="outer-card fadeInDown" style="max-width:50%;">
.
.
.
.
.
</mat-card>
```

Thank you

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I am not able to arrange the cards in the above layout. Could you please advice on how to achieve this layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using **ngx-bootstrap** as well. So, you can use something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row>
            <div class="col-12">
                <mat-card><!-- your code --></mat-card>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row>
            <div class="col-12">
                <mat-card><!-- your code --></mat-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <mat-card><!-- your code --></mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the npm install --save-dev ng2-charts-schematics.refer the link https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/07/responsive-dashboard-angular-material-ng2-charts-schematics/

```html
nav.component.html
<mat-nav-list>
     <a *ngFor="let item of menuItems" mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/'+item"> {{item | titlecase}} </a>

nav.component.ts
menuItems = ['dashboard', ’sales', 'orders', 'customers', 'products'];
```